# Monitoing of remote JVM using Jconsole

Tags: java, jconsole

I'm trying to monitor remote jvm using Jconsole. 
jdk1.7.0_75 is installed and configured the below parameter in jre/lib/management/management.properties file on remote machine.

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8002
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=x.x.x.x
```

Getting Connection failed: connection refused.
checked the port number 8002 is free and disabled the firewall, Kindly provide the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the right properties, but **mixing two different approaches here.** To enable JMX on your application you either need to:

- start your application with these **command line parameters** you used above (`java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8002 -cp somedependency.jar Appplication`)
- add similar **entries to your management.properties** BUT WITHOUT the "-D" prefixes. So entries like: `com.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8002`